Cannot assign argument to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<EventDetails[] | undefined>'
In a ReactJS project I am trying to update state that was created as such:
const [eventsData, setEventsData] = useState<EventDetails[]>();

However, when I attempt to assign the new state by calling setEventsData(obj) I encounter this Typescript compilation error:
Argument of type { _id: Id<"events">; _creationTime: number; title: string; description: string; location: string; isFree: boolean; imageUrl: string; startDateTime: any; endDateTime: any; price: string; url: string; categoryId: Id<...>; organizerId: Id<...>; category: { ...; }; organizer: { ...; }; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<EventDetails[] | undefined>


The error is caused due to mismatch in types.
Its expecting a type of  EventDetails[]>
However, you're passing in the type { _id: Id<"events">; _creationTime: number; title: string; description: string; location: string; isFree: boolean; imageUrl: string; startDateTime: any; endDateTime: any; price: string; url: string; categoryId: Id<...>; organizerId: Id<...>; category: { ...; }; organizer: { ...; }; }[] | undefined
You'll have to make sure that the returned document from the database is the same type.
